# Can't bind to 'checked' or 'indeterminate' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-checkbox'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm posting here because I didn't find any thing that may help.
I'm trying to create a [selection data table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection) using angular material,

The data that should be displayed by the table comes from laravel5.4 application.

html code:

> 

```
<!-- Checkbox Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                  [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                  [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                  (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                  [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

.....

error details:

[image]

Comment: Did you include `MatCheckboxModule` in your module specification?

Comment: @ThorJacobsen please post this as an answer, it works! thank you very much, and excuse me because I'm very green to angular.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From my comment: Remember to include the module for the component (`MatCheckboxModule` in this case)

Comment: are you talking about the statement: import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';

Answer (score 1):

import MatCheckboxModule from @angular/Material as shown below.Add below line in generated material.module.ts file.

```
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/Material'
```

And additionally i have added MatToolbarModule,MatCardModule,MatListModule for design purpose.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
MatToolbarModule,
MatCardModule,
MatCheckboxModule,
MatListModule,
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({

exports:[
MatToolbarModule,
MatCardModule,
MatCheckboxModule,
MatListModule
],

providers: [

],
declarations: []
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

And import material module in app.module.ts file so that we can use material module across the application.

```
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
```

And also add MaterialModule in imports array property of @NgModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({

declarations: [
AppComponent],

imports: [
BrowserModule,
MaterialModule
],

providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```